# Feature selection for linear regression with MCMC

Tags: distributions, feature-selection, markov-chain-montecarlo

Let $f_n(x;\beta)$ be the $n$-dimensional linear regression model, i.e:
$$f_n(x,\beta)= x^T\beta,\ x, \beta\in \mathbb{R}^n$$
I have data $(y_i,x_i)$ but I just want to use $k < n$ features in order to reduce dimensionality but i don't know in advance which features to use so I want to use mcmc to decide for me. In order to do this I need to define the transformation $T_c: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^k$ for every $c \in C(n,k)$ such that $T_c(x)$ is the vector of $k$ features represented by the combination $c$.
If we place a prior distribution  $q$ over $c \in C(n,k)$ and $p$ over $\beta \in \mathbb{R}^k$ we could have a likelihood function for the problem given by:
$$L(\beta,c,\sigma) := \prod_i\mathcal{N}(f_k(T_c(x_i)) - y_i,\sigma^2)$$
and then we could do MCMC.

To make use of standard MCMC algortithms I need to transform the discrete parameter into a continuos one but I don't know how to do this efficiently. A very brute force approach is to have an iterable $\{c_0,c_1,...,c_{N-1}\}$ of $C(n,k)$ (sort by lexicographical order for example) and then use a variable $z \in [0,1]$ that represents the combionation $c_j$ if $z \in \left[\frac{j}{N},\frac{j+1}{N}\right)$ and then place a prior over $z$ to sample the distribution. The problem I see with this low dimensional representation is that I don't really know how to implement it efficiently.

Any help on this kind of feature selection problem will be appreciated
Thanks and sorry for the bad english!

Comment: If you're interested in Bayesian variable selection, you could look at spike-and-slab models or stochastic search variable selection. If penalization is sufficient, horseshoe priors and ridge regression might also be of interest. There's also the Bayesian lasso, but my understanding is that it's a bad idea.

Comment: Not an expert on this, but I think what you are looking for is Reversible Jump MCMC (can perform model selection for you). It is a pretty well-known algorithm in Bayesian stats, so you should be able to find an introduction/tutorial somewhere online